# Deselect text programmatically

Tags: perl, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit, perltk

I am using a **Text widget**.

I have over-ridden the right click to display a popup menu in my Perl/Tk GUI. But whenever I right click at any position, the text from the earlier cursor location till the location where I have right clicked gets highlighted.

I don't know what is causing this, so I simply want to programmatically deselect this highlighted text.

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I have made a bind for right-click and this is the subroutine that is called:

```
sub rightClickMenu {
    my ($self, $x, $y) = @_;
    $txt->tagRemove('sel', '1.0', 'end');
    $rightMenu -> post($x, $y);
    $txt->tagRemove('sel', '1.0', 'end');
}
```

I have removed the **sel** tag twice (just to be sure). `$rightMenu` is the menu that is popped up. It shows perfectly fine when right-clicked.

Comment: You should show the code how you disable the popup menu. Please make the code as short as possible, by stripping unrelated stuff.

Comment: Add to that the code you use to remove the `'sel'` tag, and the code that activates the removal of the tag. Again, as little code as possible.

Comment: @Hoodiecrow I have added the code. I seriously hope I have made a mistake.

Comment: Can you dump a list of all tags set in the text 1) before and 2) after right-clicking?

Comment: How do you bind `rightClickMenu`?

Answer (score 1):

The selection in the text widget is handled by setting the tag `sel` for the selected range of characters.  This tag can be removed like this:

```
.t tag remove sel 1.0 end
```

assuming the pathname of your text widget is `.t`. This specifies that for all characters from the first (`1.0`) to the character position after the last character (`end`) the tag `sel` is to be removed.

Note: normally when removing a tag one has to deal with the possibility that it has been assigned to multiple ranges in the text.  The tag removal invocation above clears the tag from the whole text, and that's fine for the selection tag since you're (usually) only supposed to have one selected range anyway.  If there are multiple ranges that have the tag `foo` and you want to clear just one of them, you first need to find the starting and ending indices of that range and clear (by calling `tag remove`) the tag only between those.

Note 2: All this is assuming that the visible effect is actually caused by the `sel` tag getting set. In Tk, it's not a standard binding for button 2 to set this tag: it could be that some non-standard binding in Perl-Tk sets some other tag that is displayed visually in the same way as the `sel` tag is. For further investigation, this command may be useful:

```
.t tag names $placeWhereIRightClicked
```

(again assuming the pathname of your text widget is `.t`, and that `placeWhereIRightClicked` holds the index of the place where the right clicking occurred) will tell you all tags that are active at that index.

(The command

```
.t tag names
```

will list tags for the whole text.)

TkDocs has an article [about the text widget](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html) where the `tag remove` command is mentioned, but how to do it in Perl-Tk isn't showed.

The CPAN documentation for the text widget says that the syntax for the command is

```
$text->tagRemove(tagName, index1, ?index2, index1, index2, ...?)
```

so I suppose

```
$text->tagRemove('sel', '1.0', 'end')
```

or something like that is the way to do it (no Perl, can't test).

(Note: the 'Hoodiecrow' mentioned in the comments is me, I used that nick earlier.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I can help you then.  It's likely to be a Perl-Tk issue, since it works just fine with Tcl/Tk. (You _did_ substitute your own widget-holding variable for `$text`, etc, right?)

Comment: Oh! It seems the indices, even the quasi-numerical, must be strings.  Try specifying '1.0' instead.

Comment: Yes I did change it. Still nothing. The text gets selected till the position where I right click.

Comment: Even after changing the index? According to the Perl-Tk docs, this is the way to do it, so something must be set up the wrong way.  Could there possibly be another tag (besides `'sel'`) that gets set and which is displayed the same way as the selection by your text widget?

Comment: Yes, even after changing that. No, since I haven't used **tags** at all (other than what you have written above), that possibility can be ruled out.

Comment: Just to be sure: 1) you right-click, 2) the text gets selected, 3) your code removes the `'sel'` tag, 4) the text still stays selected? I.e. the events happen in that order?

Comment: Yes. Exactly in that order!